# Multiline hidden text with align environment

Tags: support, mathjax, markdown, spoilers

Is there a way to use `>!` for hidden lines with the `\begin{align*} ... \end{align*}` environment? I can't seem to get it to work. Any workarounds?

Comment: Or did you want to hide single lines within an align environment?

Comment: That's not what I had in mind, but if you know how, I'd be interested to learn

Comment: No idea how one could do that. Don't know if that's even possible.

Comment: Please use spoilers very sparingly.

Comment: @quid, what's your reasoning? (I'm not necessarily disagreeing, just wondering.)

Comment: It makes it more inconvenient to get access to  information. This is counter the purpose of the site.

Comment: See also: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9297/how-to-put-math-equations-in-a-spoiler-block 
http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10906/big-tex-wont-get-hidden-by
http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19838/spoiler-markup-broken-for-multilined-display-math

Answer (score 3):

Write the source on a single line:

`>! \begin{align*} 0 &= 1^2 - 1^3 \\ 4 + 1 &= 5 \\ 6 - 7 &= -1\end{align*}` produces

> \begin{align*} 0 &= 1^2 - 1^3 \\ 4 + 1 &= 5 \\ 6 - 7 &= -1\end{align*}

Comment: Great, thanks! Do you know of any other solutions that will make the code easier to read/edit later?

Comment: 'fraid not. Originally, you can write the code normally, and then remove the newlines to get it on one line. But after that … well, you can insert newlines when editing, but it's always going to be inconvenient.