# How To Hide An Array on MathSE

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, mathjax, spoilers

I constructed a (long) self-answer, that I subsequently discarded, since I found that the question + answer was a duplicate.  I intended to have the answer hidden.

I had trouble converting the following array to a hidden format:

\begin{array}{| r | r | r | r |}
  \hline                       
  \text{Case} & n & n+1 & 2n+1 \\
  \hline
  1 & 2a^2 & 3b^2 & c^2 \\
  \hline
  2 & 2a^2 & b^2 & 3c^2 \\
  \hline
  3 & a^2 & 2b^2 & 3c^2 \\
  \hline
  4 & 3a^2 & 2b^2 & c^2 \\
  \hline
  5 & 6a^2 & b^2 & c^2 \\
  \hline
  6 & a^2 & 6b^2 & c^2 \\
  \hline
\end{array}

---

What I settled for is this:

> --------------------------------------------
> ----------
> Case $~~~~~~~n$ $~~~~~~~~n+1$ $~~~~~~2n+1$ 
> --------------------------------------------
> ----------
> $~~~~1$ $~~~~~~2a^2$  $~~~~~~~~~~3b^2$ $~~~~~~~~~~~~~c^2$ 
> --------------------------------------------
> ----------
> $~~~~2$ $~~~~~~2a^2$  $~~~~~~~~~~~b^2$ $~~~~~~~~~~~~3c^2$ 
> --------------------------------------------
> ----------
> $~~~~3$ $~~~~~~~a^2$  $~~~~~~~~~~2b^2$ $~~~~~~~~~~~~3c^2$ 
> --------------------------------------------
> ----------
> $~~~~4$ $~~~~~~3a^2$  $~~~~~~~~~~2b^2$ $~~~~~~~~~~~~~c^2$ 
> --------------------------------------------
> ----------
> $~~~~5$ $~~~~~~6a^2$  $~~~~~~~~~~~b^2$ $~~~~~~~~~~~~~c^2$ 
> --------------------------------------------
> ----------
> $~~~~6$ $~~~~~~~a^2$  $~~~~~~~~~~6b^2$ $~~~~~~~~~~~~~c^2$ 
> --------------------------------------------
> ----------

---

You can review the code that I used by *pretending* to edit the question.

Questions:

1. At the present time, on mathSE, is this the best that I can do?
2. If so, how much trouble would it be for a moderator to enhance the html or mathJax capabilities at mathSE to facilitate including tabular/array of data in a hidden answer?

Comment: An idea would be to use tables, but it seems that tables [don't work in spoilers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support/357005#357005).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a community answer for purposes of testing.

The text from the question posted as a spoiler.

> ! \begin{array}{| r | r | r | r |}  \hline                       
> >!   \text{Case} & n & n+1 & 2n+1 \\  \hline
> >!   1 & 2a^2 & 3b^2 & c^2 \\  \hline
> >!   2 & 2a^2 & b^2 & 3c^2 \\  \hline
> >!   3 & a^2 & 2b^2 & 3c^2 \\  \hline
> >!   4 & 3a^2 & 2b^2 & c^2 \\  \hline
> >!   5 & 6a^2 & b^2 & c^2 \\  \hline
> >!   6 & a^2 & 6b^2 & c^2 \\  \hline
> >! \end{array}

The same text, but now in a single line as suggested in: [Multiline hidden text with align environment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/23107#23108).

> \begin{array}{| r | r | r | r |}  \hline                         \text{Case} & n & n+1 & 2n+1 \\  \hline  1 & 2a^2 & 3b^2 & c^2 \\  \hline  2 & 2a^2 & b^2 & 3c^2 \\  \hline  3 & a^2 & 2b^2 & 3c^2 \\  \hline  4 & 3a^2 & 2b^2 & c^2 \\  \hline  5 & 6a^2 & b^2 & c^2 \\  \hline  6 & a^2 & 6b^2 & c^2 \\  \hline\end{array}

One might be tempted to try a table:

| Case | $n$ | $n+1$ | $2n+1$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $1$ | $2a^2$ | $3b^2$ | $c^2$ |
| $2$ | $2a^2$ | $b^2$ | $3c^2$ |
| $3$ | $ a^2$ | $2b^2$ | $3c^2$ |
| $4$ | $3a^2$ | $2b^2$ | $c^2$ |
| $5$ | $6a^2$ | $b^2$ | $c^2$ |
| $6$ | $a^2$ | $6b^2$ | $c^2$ |

But the tables [do not work in spoilers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support/357005#357005):

> | Case  | $n$ | $n+1$ | $2n+1$ |
>  |------|---|---|---|
>  |  $1$ | $2a^2$ | $3b^2$ | $c^2$ |
>  |  $2$ | $2a^2$ |  $b^2$ | $3c^2$ |
>  |  $3$ | $ a^2$ | $2b^2$ | $3c^2$ |
>  |  $4$ | $3a^2$ | $2b^2$ | $c^2$ |
>  |  $5$ | $6a^2$ |  $b^2$ | $c^2$ |
>  |  $6$ |  $a^2$ | $6b^2$ | $c^2$ |

From [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13738/80734) answer of achille hui:

$$\require{action}
\toggle{
\text{(Click to show table)}
}{
\begin{array}{c}
 \begin{array}{| r | r | r | r |}  \hline                         \text{Case} & n & n+1 & 2n+1 \\  \hline  1 & 2a^2 & 3b^2 & c^2 \\  \hline  2 & 2a^2 & b^2 & 3c^2 \\  \hline  3 & a^2 & 2b^2 & 3c^2 \\  \hline  4 & 3a^2 & 2b^2 & c^2 \\  \hline  5 & 6a^2 & b^2 & c^2 \\  \hline  6 & a^2 & 6b^2 & c^2 \\  \hline\end{array}\\
 \text{(Click to hide table)}
\end{array}
}
\endtoggle$$

Comment: Nice trick. However I am used to writing arrays in multi-line.

Comment: So you're saying that you can't spoil a table? Or that tables are already spoiled?

Comment: +1 and accepted.  Sharp answer.

Comment: I will stress that this was intended as a space where various users can test their ideas how to do this. (That's why I made the answer CW.) So if you have some other ideas, do not hesitate to edit this further.

Comment: @user2661923 I adapted a legendary answer of achille hui